# Como actualizar la cantidad de productos de un carrito de compras con Observables y Angular

Tags: angular, ionic, observable

Tengo una app en ionic, en la cual hago una peticion a una api, de los productos del changuito asi
En el .ts

```
this._listadoProductosService.getProductos(paginaActual,cantidad,segment,queryText,origen,familias,this.idUsuarioLogueado).subscribe(      
  (data) => {       
    for (const d of (data as any)) {
      this.productos_lista.push({
        precio_compra: d.precio_compra,
        precio: d.precio,          
      });
  }
```

En el servicio:

```
getProductos(paginaActual:number,cantidad:number,segment:string,descripcion:string,origen:string,familias:string,id_usuario_logueado:string):Observable<any>{  //para menu  ,'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'

var mheaders = "";
let body={};


 body = { 
  accion: "listado", 
  descrip:descripcion, 
  paginaActual:paginaActual,
  cantPorPagina:cantidad
      
}  
     break; 
  }
```

}
return this._http.post(`${this.api_url}`, body);
}

Hasta acá todo bien, en this.productos_lista tengo los productos y los listo en una vista con NGFOR.
El tema es que no entiendo de todo los observables y las subscripciones y demás.
Tengo otro componente, en el cual deseo poner la cantidad de productos del carrito, osea, cuando llamo a insertar un producto en el carrito, que también funciona bien:

```
this._listadoProductosService.guardarEnCarrito(id_producto,this.idUsuarioLogueado).subscribe(
     async (data) => {                       
     const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
      header:data[0].mensaje,//ej:mensaje guardado ok
      duration: 3000,
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Cerrar',
        role: 'cancel'
      }]
    });
```

y en el servicio el guardar seria
guardarEnCarrito(id_producto,user_id):Observable{
const mheaders = "";
const body = {
accion: "agr_c",
id_producto: id_producto,
user_id: user_id,
}
return this._http.post(`${this.api_url_guardar}`, JSON.stringify(body));
}

Ahora como hago que cada vez que guardo algo en el carrito, se me actualize una variable , que tengo en otro componente, que es un carrito con un nro en rojo al lado, que es la cantidad de productos en el carrito, no entiendo como debo subscribirme para que ese componente ve el cambio y automáticamente cambie de 2 a 3 la cantidad de productos por ejemplo, muchas gracias

Comment: Creo que lo que estas buscando es [ngrx](https://ngrx.io/guide/store), tiene una curva de aprendizaje moderada, pero te ayuda a mantener un estado entre componentes.

Comment: si lo se, pero no logro entenderlo, lo he leído, quizá quiero empezar, por lo menos, emitiendo un mensaje cada vez que recargo el listado de productos, al componente que muestra la cantidad, mediante algún servicio con emiters, viewchild,  o algo, pero no encuentro un ejemplo claro

Comment: Mira este [ejemplo que realice](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-42gt3a?file=src/app/cart.component.ts), puede que te sirva, coméntame si te ayudó para documentarlo como respuesta.